# Skipping a line of code when a condition is met in R

Tags: r, character

I am trying to skip a line of code based on a condition. Here my sample dataset looks like.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(12,25,31,47),
  b = c("cat.1","cat.2","cat.3","cat.2"),
  drop = c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))

> df
  id     b  drop
1 12 cat.1 FALSE
2 25 cat.2  TRUE
3 31 cat.3  TRUE
4 47 cat.2  TRUE
```

Based on the `b` and `drop` variables, I print different `out` and combine them in the `output`. I would like to skip a line code when `drop` = `FALSE`.

```
output <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$b[i] == "cat.1") {
    out <- paste0("Item_first_",df$id[i],"_",df$drop[i])
    
  } else if(df$b[i] == "cat.2") { 
    out <- paste0("Item_second_",df$id[i],"_",df$drop[i])
    
  } else {
    out <- paste0("Item_others_",df$id[i],"_",df$drop[i])
  }
  output <- c(output, out) 
}

print(output)
[1] "Item_first_12_FALSE" "Item_second_25_TRUE" "Item_others_31_TRUE" "Item_second_47_TRUE"
```

In this case,  `"Item_first_12_FALSE"` needs to be dropped from the output because this row in the dataset has the `drop`=`FALSE`.

I know there is `next` function in `for()` loops but it avoids the whole iteration. And also, it looks easy to fix by just removing the `FALSE` from the dataset but I specifically want to omit it inside of the `ifelse` because of the other condition combinations. IN this case, I need only skip this part meeting the `drop`=`FALSE' condition.

```
 if (df$b[i] == "cat.1") {
    out <- paste0("Item_first_",df$id[i],"_",df$drop[i])
    
  }
```

The desired output would be:

```
"Item_second_25_TRUE" "Item_others_31_TRUE" "Item_second_47_TRUE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your if-else within another if statement:

```
output <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$drop[i] == T) {
    if (df$b[i] == "cat.1") {
      out <- paste0("Item_first_",df$id[i],"_",df$drop[i])
      
    } else if(df$b[i] == "cat.2") { 
      out <- paste0("Item_second_",df$id[i],"_",df$drop[i])
      
    } else {
      out <- paste0("Item_others_",df$id[i],"_",df$drop[i])
    }
    output <- c(output, out)
  }  
}
```

```
> print(output)
[1] "Item_second_25_TRUE" "Item_others_31_TRUE" "Item_second_47_TRUE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just do something like this

```
with(df, sprintf("Item_%s_%d_%s", dplyr::case_when(b == "cat.1" ~ "first", b == "cat.2" ~ "second", TRUE ~ "others"), id, drop)[drop])
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have to have the `for` loop

```
output <- unlist(ifelse((df$b == "cat.1"),list(NULL),paste("Item_second_",df$id,df$drop, sep="_")))

print (output)
#  "Item_second__25_TRUE" "Item_second__31_TRUE" "Item_second__47_TRUE"
```